# error installing graphviz 2.40.1 app on mac os 10.13.6 with xcode 10

Tags: macos, graphviz

Here is the terminal log. Any suggestions?

> Last login: Tue Sep 18 18:31:24 on console Marks-MacBook-Pro:~
>   markklein$ brew uninstall graphviz Error: No such keg:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/graphviz Marks-MacBook-Pro:~ markklein$ brew install
>   graphviz --with-app
>   ==> Downloading https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/distfiles.macports.org/graph
>   Already downloaded:
>   /Users/markklein/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/1c469743457f48b96f1f3fca3f9444a15736b2840413f31cc7e5f4a6bb5c8510--graphviz-2.40.1.tar.gz
>   ==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1 --without-qt --with-q
>   ==> make install
>   ==> xcodebuild SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacO Last
>   15 lines from
>   /Users/markklein/Library/Logs/Homebrew/graphviz/03.xcodebuild:    25 
>   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff55528015 start + 1  26 
>   ???                                 0x0000000000000015 0x0 + 21 )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException Command CompileXIB failed with a nonzero exit code
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  CompileXIB
>   /tmp/graphviz-20180918-1135-ze21bq/graphviz-2.40.1/macosx/English.lproj/MainMenu.xib
>     CompileXIB
>   /tmp/graphviz-20180918-1135-ze21bq/graphviz-2.40.1/macosx/English.lproj/Export.xib
>     CompileXIB
>   /tmp/graphviz-20180918-1135-ze21bq/graphviz-2.40.1/macosx/English.lproj/Document.xib
>     CompileXIB
>   /tmp/graphviz-20180918-1135-ze21bq/graphviz-2.40.1/macosx/English.lproj/Attributes.xib
>   (4 failures) /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:49:in
>   `write': Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)   from
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:49:in`puts'   from
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:49:in `rescue in
>   block (3 levels) in safe_fork'    from
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:31:in`block (3
>   levels) in safe_fork'     from
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:30:in `fork'   from
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:30:in`block (2
>   levels) in safe_fork'     from
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:27:in `open'   from
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:27:in`block in
>   safe_fork'    from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:89:in
>   `mktmpdir'    from
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:26:in`safe_fork'
>     from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:719:in
>   `build'   from
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:311:in`
>   install'     from
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:321:in
>   `install_formula'     from
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:253:in`block in
>   install'  from
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:251:in `each'
>     from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:251:in`
>   install'     from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:89:in
>   `'
>
> READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting
>
> Marks-MacBook-Pro:~ markklein$

Comment: If you want help with this problem I recommend you to open an issue in the issue tracker of [Homebrew Core project](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

-update Xcode from App store

-open Xcode from the applications and accept any new terms

-brew upgrade

-brew uninstall graphviz

-brew install graphviz --with-app

Comment: Second time I've seen `--with-app`.  `Error: invalid option: --with-app`